# Silverlight Pivotviewer 2 control slow loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvvm, silverlight-5.0, pivotviewer

In my project, I use PivotViewer-2 to visually display all data elements of an entity in one card. There are 50+ data elements that needs to be stacked in a single card. I defined a template (let's say T4) with all required data elements. For few data elements, I use value Converter classes to interpret into UI usable values.

The Silverlight Pivotviewer 2 client sources data by calling a web service and gets an Object Collection and assigns to PivotViewer's ItemSource property. The rendering of cards works good with less data (50). When the count increases, performance of pivotviewer comes down dramatically. The typical business scenario is 4000-5000 records.

I tested with 4025 records and it took almost 75 seconds to render data in the pivot viewer. The 75 second is counted from the time data assigned to item source to full rendering of pivot viewer. After the first load it works normally as expected.

- I introduced 3 more templates (T1, T2, T3) with 1, 2 and 3 data elements to display respectively. The pivot viewer assigned with 4 templates T1, T2, T3, T4 in that order. It it took 82 seconds to load.
- I cut-down the T4 template [which is a heavy-weight template with 50+ display elements] and the load/rendering took 22 seconds.

Please suggest how effectively we can load large data into pivot viewer.

Are there any workaround to load the pivot viewer with simple template first and then add more complex template dynamically in the background.